# Is Flanitor a Good Medic Type?

Tags: final-fantasy-13-2

I just got to **Augusta Tower (300 AF)** and encountered the **Flanitor** monster, who is a `MED` type. `MED` monsters are relatively uncommon so far, as I'm still using **Cait Sith** whom you get almost immediately when the game begins.

**Flanitor** seems to be somewhat rare compared to the other monster groups in the area. Also, I've killed about 10 so far and haven't been able to tame one. Before I waste too much more time can someone let me know if **Flanitor** is significantly better than other `MED` types at this point in the game?

Comment: Flanitor level 40 3500+hp 400+atk 750+ magic

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Flanitor has one great thing about him - of all the medics he learns Esunaga (Esuna on all) on the lowest level.  Also, his Feral Link truly is a lifesaver.  If you are about to be flattened, use his Feral Link, and when you are on full hitpoints he will cheer himself up so he can use it.

Flanitor is great but listen to this. You want Flanitor for the early Esuna. You also want the catigipillar (sp) who is the only monster in the game that learns elemental resist +30%. and it also learns raise real early so if you get it while your Flanitor is a low level, quickly level him up until he get eleresist and raise then infuse it into Flanitor.  Then when Flanitor reaches level 34 and learns Esunaga (most of the game should be done by this point) infuse the Flanitor into a Green Chocobo for the single greatest medic in the world. Just infuse your Cait Sith with your Flanitor.

Comment: +1 And I like the proposed progression of `Cait Sith -> Flanitor -> Green Chocobo`

Answer (score 2):

Cait Sith ramps up rapidly later on, and can learn more abilities than Flanitor. Personally, I'm sticking him.

Comment: Good to know, I've been using Spiranthes (Yaschas Massif - 010 AF). I might start putting points into Cait Sith instead.

Answer (score 1):

Good healing but abysmal HP, but if you are using Cait Sith it is probably better

Comment: Which `Cur---` spells does Flanitor learn vs. Cait Sith?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Green Chocobo is one of the best. He healed a lot more then Flanitor when I first got him, though he needs to be at least level 40 before he manages to do a decent heal. Also on the plus side he just looks great.

Answer (score 0):

As a MED, the Flanitor is very  good..  His liberal use of Esunaga is very useful in boss fights that loves to cast multiple status ailments(of course you can infuse this skill to your other monster MED ). The thing that distinguishes the Flanitor from other MEDs is its feral link.  “Hyper rescue” is a life saver in boss fights especially when your party are borderline dead. I know it's saved me a couple of times in the boss fights with Caius (4th version).  It drastically cuts back the healing time during boss fights.

*Is he the best MED in the game?* Probably not, that still a subject for debate (and no I don’t have the green Chocobo yet so I can’t say).  I guess it comes down with your fighting style and strategy.. If you like to press on the aggression then do a quick insta-heal in between(timing is a necessity of course) then the Flanitor is your man.. or Flan.